# Angular: How to disable an anchor tag out of an array (ng-repeat) of anchor tags

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, anchor, disabled-input

I have an ng-repeat of anchor tags that is displaying a list of clickable group memebers:

```
<a href="#/contact/{{ ::member.fullProfile.xpid }}" ng-click="storeRecentContact(member.fullProfile.xpid)" class=" GroupRow ListRow ListRow-Contact vmsection ng-class:{'last': $last}" ng-class-odd="'ListRowOdd'" ng-class="{'ListRowLast':$last}" data-ng-repeat="member in group.members | filter: searchFilter() | orderBy: [selectedSort.type, 'fullProfile.displayName'] track by member.xpid" droppable="Call" ng-disabled="member.contactId == myself.contactId">
```

As you can see at the end of the anchor tag, I am trying to disable 1 of the ng-repeat elements, more specifically, the anchor tag of me/myself.

```
myself.contactId
```

and

```
member.contactId
```

will be the same on the anchor tag representing my user. However, it is still not disabling my ability to click on my own group member anchor tag. Am I utilizing ng-disabled correctly? Or alternatively, is there another way of accomplishing this?

Comment: There is no disabled attribute on the `a`tag. Ng-disabled works only on tags with a disabled attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could not disable `<a>` anchor tag, you should try a simpler way to do by handling logic on html itself using `&&` check like first check `member.contactId != myself.contactId` and if its true then only fire `storeRecentContact(member.fullProfile.xpid)` method.

here you ng-click should look like `ng-click="member.contactId != myself.contactId && storeRecentContact(member.fullProfile.xpid)"` now you can remove `ng-disabled` directive which is of no use.

**Markup**

```
<a href="#/contact/{{ ::member.fullProfile.xpid }}" 
ng-click="member.contactId != myself.contactId && storeRecentContact(member.fullProfile.xpid)" 
...other attributes..
.....
></a>
```

[**Small Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/lTCv8BlvtTRRfqGFWDnR?p=preview)

**Update**

To stop redirecting your link to different page you could use `ng-attr` directive that will set an `href` tag value(where you want to redirect your SPA) by evaluation `{{}}` expression. If you want to redirect to `#/contact/1` then your `href` would be `href="#/contact/{{ ::member.fullProfile.xpid }}"` otherwise it would be simply `href=""` as blank. Suppose as you are using a condition that `member.contactId` shouldn't be equal to `member.contactId` like `member.contactId != myself.contactId` then you don't want user to redirect your SPA on contact details page. That thing will handle by `{{member.contactId != myself.contactId' ? #/contact/'+ member.fullProfile.xpid: '' }}` of `ng-attr-href` this will change `href` attribute value on basis of `{{}}` expression

```
<a ng-attr-href="{{member.contactId != myself.contactId' ? #/contact/'+ member.fullProfile.xpid: '' }}" 
   ng-click="member.contactId != myself.contactId &&  storeRecentContact(member.fullProfile.xpid)" 
   ...other attributes..
   .....
></a>
```

Comment: Thanks @pankajparkar, but that is not working. I'm pretty sure the ng-click function "storeRecentContact" is not what enables the element to be clicked, but the fact that it is an anchor tag is what makes it clickable.

Comment: @Seeeyonnn see here is demo plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/lTCv8BlvtTRRfqGFWDnR?p=preview you should have missed something

Comment: Your plunker is overlooking my ng-repeat of anchor tags I think. I'm looking into your update re: ng-attr, @pankajparkar, maybe you can elaborate a little?

Comment: ^ is the redirecting that I am trying to stop. I want to redirect to that href UNLESS, member.contactId == myself.contactId...

Comment: @Seeeyonnn I think its more clearer now..try the suggested one please.and let me know..it works or not

Comment: @Seeeyonnn Glad to here that it work..you could do ask question..if you are not clear on anything..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79862/discussion-between-seeeyonnn-and-pankajparkar).

Answer (score 1):

`ng-disabled` creates the disabled attribute which is only used for inputs.

An anchor tag is not an input, therefore cannot be disabled. What you want to do is change the way you address this problem. You might want to hide it (the `a` element), you might want a directive to remove the `href` or replace it to "#" or something based on your condition.

You can also do:

`ng-href="{{getRef(member, mySelf)}}"` and calculate this from your controller. If your condition is false and this should be shown normally, just return the normal link. Otherwise, you can return `#`:

```
$scope.getRef = function(member, myself) {
    if (member.contactId == myself.contactId) { 
        return "#";
    }
    else {
        return "#/contact/" + member.fullProfile.xpid;
    }
}
```

Comment: this will affect the routing & resultant would be SPA gets messed up

Comment: @Omri Aharon this is resulting in a javascript error, as "member" can't be read - tried both $scope.member and member in the js code...

Comment: @Seeeyonnn try the updated one..he has missed to pass those parameter

Comment: Thanks, both answers ended up working, those function parameters were necessary. Still upvoted appreciated the time invested by both of you

Comment: @Seeeyonnn Glad to help you bro..I think you've understood the concept. :)